# Secure https redirect with github pages and letsencrypt doesn't work

Tags: ssl, https, dns, github-pages

I have two domains: example.com and example.org.

```
HTTP://www.example.com redirects to HTTPS://www.example.org (as expected)  
HTTP://example.com redirects to HTTPS://www.example.org (as expected)  
HTTP://www.example.org redirects to HTTPS://www.example.org (as expected)  
HTTP://example.org redirects to HTTPS://www.example.org (as expected)  
HTTPS://example.org redirects to HTTPS://www.example.org (as expected)
```

However, using HTTP**S** doesn't work. I think this is because I haven't proven that I own example.com to my CA (letsencrypt through GitHub pages).

```
HTTPS://www.example.com should redirect to HTTPS://www.example.org  
HTTPS://example.com should redirect to HTTPS://www.example.org
```

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/167395/redirect-https-to-another-https) question is related but it goes a little over my head and I'm not sure how to implement it on Github pages with Namecheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by migrating to netlify. I recommend.

I used the information [here](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/) and [here](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#domain-level-redirects) to create a _redirects file that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/* https://www.example.org/:splat 301!
https://www.example.com/* https://www.example.org/:splat 301!
http://example.com/* https://www.example.org/:splat 301!
http://www.example.com/* https://www.example.org/:splat 301!
```